# Опреление возраста по дате

Tags: php

Подскажите, как можно узнать, сколько лет пользователю, если он ввел только дату рождения, но не число, указывающее возраст? Кто-нибудь сталкивался с этой проблемой? Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать, если возможно, подкиньте пример. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$birthday = '1985-04-15'; //Дата рождения

$age = floor( ( time() - strtotime($birthday) ) / (60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25) ); //Формула

echo $age; //27
```

Comment: Проверил и не понял. Вроде правильно, но:

`$birthday = '1985-08-30'; //Дата рождения

$age = round( ( time() - strtotime($birthday) ) / (60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25) ); //Формула

echo $age; //27`

Почему 27? Ведь 27 будет только 30.08

Comment: Да, ты прав. Все-таки floor().

Comment: Делить на 365.25 - это грубое получение даты рождения, будет погрешность в несколько дней. Дал ответ, как получить точно.

Answer (score 2):

Данную задачу можно выполнить еще с помощью PHP функции [date_diff](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.diff.php) или [DateTime::diff](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.diff.php), что в принципе одно и тоже. *DateTime::diff -- date_diff — Возвращает разницу между двумя DateTime объектами*. Также эту задачу можно решить с помощью MySQL функции [DATEDIFF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff).

Answer (score 1):

Функциональный стиль - определение возраста в годах на момент времени $ageTime:

```
function getAge($birthdate, $ageTime = null/*now by default*/){
        return (new DateTime())
                ->setTimestamp($ageTime ? $ageTime : time())
                ->diff(new DateTime($birthdate))->format('%Y');
}
```